# Code Igniter Controller/Model name conflicts

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller and model both named "account" without getting "cannot redeclare class".  I'd like to add a prefix to Models or Controllers, or preferably both.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you prefix `Model_` and `Controller_` respectively?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you call your model "account_model" and reference it like this:

```
$this->load->model('account_model', 'account');
$this->account->function();
```

I know it doesn't solve the problem, however I think that you might find it an adequate solution!

Comment: This is a really great answer and a very simple solution.  Modifying the underlying framework is not at all necessary, especially when @Henry notes that Codeigniter provides a means to give your model an alias on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an issue with this. if it was me, i would be a bit more descriptive with the prefix so you remember what the model or controller was for. I only say this because "account" is a little vague.