# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a login system using codeigniter but there is a fatal error found when trying to login :(

## Controler Auth.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Auth/login','',TRUE);
}

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // $this->load->view('Home');
    }

    // start login
   public function login()
   {
      $this->load->helper(array('form'));
      $this->load->view('Login');
   }
   // end login

   // start logout
   public function logout()
   {
       $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
       redirect('Login','refresh');
   }
   // end logout


// start checkLogin
public function checkLogin()
{
    // field validation successfull, validate against database 
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    // query database
    $this->load->model('Auth');
    $result = $this->Auth->login($username, $password);

    if ($result) {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $sess_array = array(
                $id = $row->id,
                $username = $row->username
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkLogin', 'Invalid username or password');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
// end checkLogin

}
```

## Models Auth.php

```
<?php

class Auth extends CI_Model
{
    // start login
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('id','username','password');
        $this->db->from('user_details');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    // end login
}
?>
```

### please help me to find the exact error I have done :'(

Comment: Did you called your `construct` function above class definition

Comment: Which version of CI you use???

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.0 version

Comment: _I'm trying to make a login system using codeigniter but there is a **fatal error** found when trying to login :(_ Post that error too

Comment: yeah I called the construct function in controller (Auth.php)

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Auth in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\office\dvdstore\application\models\Auth.php on line 22
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Compile Error

Message: Cannot redeclare class Auth

Filename: models/Auth.php

Line Number: 22

Backtrace:

Comment: `parent::__construct();` doesn't make any sense as you're calling constructor before the scope of class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864201/code-igniter-controller-model-name-conflicts#comment6740776_5864201

Comment: construct function outside class?what experiment you doing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two class with same name `Auth` one for controller and one for model.One script cannot contain two class that's why you got that error.

Rename your auth model like this Auth_model.php and declare class like this

```
class Auth_model extends CI_Model
```

Hope you can do rest how to use this model.

Comment: Thanks but now it's give another error :(

**Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on null in**

Comment: check the following errors please

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/243095/2FzOriP5eFBZsTInOMBN9fGAPOF9FIUe/

Comment: If you have different question you should ask another question or you can search for it at SO.`Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata()` means you using `Session` class but you did not load it.